# Get the waypoint on the street instead of the original position in here maps?

Tags: android, here-api

I am requesting a route with the android premium sdk. Works as intened, but my waypoints for the request can be away from a street, for example the request was made with a location inside a building.

How can i get the mapped waypoints in the android SDK?
I saw something in the rest api.

```
            waypoint": [
                {
                    "linkId": "-1200551084",
                    "mappedPosition": {
                        "latitude": 47.0243827,
                        "longitude": 15.48219
                    },
                    "originalPosition": {
                        "latitude": 47.0243825,
                        "longitude": 15.48219
                    },
                    "type": "stopOver",
                    "spot": 0.2363636,
                    "sideOfStreet": "neither",
                    "mappedRoadName": "",
                    "label": "",
                    "shapeIndex": 0
              }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Route Object to get these values.

Using [Route](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/Route.html). getRouteWaypoints(), you can then get either the [RouteWaypoint](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RouteWaypoint.html) getNavigablePosition() or getOriginalPosition().